# How can we override standard Salesforce Lightning message?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, toast

We have custom logic to assign opportunity owner, when the User manually try to change the owner Apex code kicks in and assign the owner according to the logic.
Still Lightning Users are getting the lightning success message for owner change(manual input) which is misleading to user [image: r].
How can we override standard Salesforce Lightning message ?